# Sql Server -- Strip off non numeric characters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestAB](
    [A] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [B] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TestAB] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [A] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Values Like

```
INSERT INTO [TestAB]([B]) 
    VALUES('A1');

INSERT INTO [TestAB]([B]) 
    VALUES('A2');

INSERT INTO [TestAB]([B]) 
    VALUES('A5');

INSERT INTO [TestAB]([B]) 
    VALUES('A4');

INSERT INTO [TestAB]([B]) 
    VALUES('AA5');

INSERT INTO [TestAB]([B]) 
    VALUES('A9');

INSERT INTO [TestAB]([B]) 
    VALUES('C7');

INSERT INTO [TestAB]([B]) 
    VALUES('D8');

INSERT INTO [TestAB]([B]) 
    VALUES('D-9');

INSERT INTO [TestAB]([B]) 
    VALUES('R$10');
```

[image: Table Select]

[image: Table Design]

I want to strip off the non numeric characters and cast the nvarchar numbers to int and then compare where they are !=

Comment: See http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/13/sql-server-udf-function-to-parse-alphanumeric-characters-from-string/

Comment: Is B always non-digits followed by digits?  As in, never `X10Y`?  Is your 9th entry supposed to be 9 or -9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select A,B,Case when A<>B then 0 else 1 end
from
(
select
A,
Cast(
Left(SubString(B, PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', B), 100),
     PatIndex('%[^0-9.-]%', SubString(B, PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', B), 100)+'_' )-1)
as int) as B
from TestAB
) aa 
where A<>B
```

[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/96a40/4)

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify exactly which rows should be returned, but I think this does what you want:

```
select A, B
from dbo.TestAB
where cast(replace(B, replace(B, cast(A as nvarchar(10)), ''), '') as int) <> A
```

Comment: as he spezified != I'd believe he want's to see 3,5  6,9  9,-9

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [recursive CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx) version of [Pinal Dave's UDF](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/13/sql-server-udf-function-to-parse-alphanumeric-characters-from-string/), though we're stripping anything but digits:

```
;with digitsOnly as (
    select A, B, B as DigitB, patindex(N'%[^0-9]%', B) as IncorrectCharLoc
    from TestAB
    union all
    select A, B, cast(stuff(DigitB, IncorrectCharLoc, 1, N'') as nvarchar(10))
        , patindex(N'%[^0-9]%', stuff(DigitB, IncorrectCharLoc, 1, N''))
    from digitsOnly
    where IncorrectCharLoc > 0
)
select A, B, DigitB
from digitsOnly
where IncorrectCharLoc = 0 -- Get last iteration
    and cast(A as nvarchar(10)) <> DigitB -- Final compare
order by A
option (maxrecursion 0)

/*
    A           B          DigitB
    ----------- ---------- ----------
    3           A5         5
    6           A9         9
*/
```