# SQL Server : How to test if a string has only digit characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working in SQL Server 2008.  I am trying to test whether a string (varchar) has only digit characters (0-9).  I know that the IS_NUMERIC function can give spurious results.  (My data can possibly have $ signs, which should not pass the test.)  So, I'm avoiding that function.

I already have a test to see if a string has any non-digit characters, i.e.,

```
some_column LIKE '%[^0123456789]%'
```

I would think that the only-digits test would be something similar, but I'm drawing a blank.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you care if the string can be successfully parsed into one of the numeric types on SQL Server or not? I mean, this wouldn't be parsed, too long, but only contains digits: "9834759837459837983759837598739587398573985739875938759387593875938759387598375938759387593875938759387593875938759873495837958734985743983479837938759387593875983475"

Comment: The answer here could be adapted to suit your need:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16309072/sql-server-strip-off-non-numeric-characters

Comment: If you only need the opposite result set, just negate your where predicate: `some_colum NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'`

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Use `Not Like`

```
where some_column NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

### Demo

```
declare @str varchar(50)='50'--'asdarew345'

select 1 where @str NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

Comment: You're using a double negative. (`^` negates the character class). Why not just use `where some_column LIKE '%[0-9]%'`?

Comment: @jpaugh - Because the requirement is to find if the string has ONLY digits. Your query will return alphanumeric string as well.

Comment: You're right! I wasn't thinking too closely about the `%` before and after the character class.

Comment: This returns empty strings too

Answer (score 19):

There is a system function called [ISNUMERIC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) for SQL 2008 and up. An example:

```
SELECT myCol
FROM mTable
WHERE ISNUMERIC(myCol)<> 1;
```

I did a couple of quick tests and also looked further into the docs:

`ISNUMERIC returns 1 when the input expression evaluates to a valid numeric data type; otherwise it returns 0.`

Which means it is fairly predictable for example

`-9879210433` would pass but `987921-0433` does not.
`$9879210433` would pass but `9879210$433` does not.

So using this information you can weed out based on the [list of valid currency symbols](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179882.aspx) and `+` & `-` characters.

Comment: Oh geez, I only now saw this from the question: `IS_NUMERIC function can give spurious results.` ooops

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8840171/3726096) to restrict `IS_NUMERIC` only to integer values.

Comment: BTW, IsNumeric returns 1 (i.e. true) for strings like 1,2,3,4

Comment: And for some reason a carriage return passes the isnumeric test

Answer (score 3):

Solution: 
    `where some_column NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'`
Is correct.

Just one important note: Add validation for when the string column = `''` (empty string). This scenario will return that `''` is a valid number as well.

Comment: Your formatting seems to be incorrect, would you mind fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

Method that will work. The way it is used above will not work.

```
declare @str varchar(50)='79136'

select 
  case 
    when  @str LIKE replicate('[0-9]',LEN(@str)) then 1 
    else 0 
  end

declare @str2 varchar(50)='79D136'

select 
  case 
    when  @str2 LIKE replicate('[0-9]',LEN(@str)) then 1 
    else 0 
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @x int=1
declare @exit bit=1
WHILE @x<=len('123c') AND @exit=1
BEGIN
IF ascii(SUBSTRING('123c',@x,1)) BETWEEN 48 AND 57
BEGIN
set @x=@x+1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SET @exit=0
PRINT 'string is not all numeric  -:('
END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I was attempting to find strings with numbers ONLY, no punctuation or anything else.  I finally found an answer that would work [here](http://www.kuljeetsingh.com/How-To-Check-If-String-Contains-Numeric-Number-SQL-Server).

Using PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', some_column) = 0 allowed me to filter out everything but actual number strings.

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer does not work.

```
declare @str varchar(50)='79D136'
```

```
select 1 where @str NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

I don't have a solution but know of this potential pitfall.  The same goes if you substitute the letter 'D' for 'E' which is scientific notation.

Comment: It does not return 1, at least on my sql server. It is expected behavior because 79D136 or 79E136 is not an integer

Answer (score 0):

**ITS WORKS!!!**

```
SELECT my_field FROM my_table WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(my_field, '[^0-9]') - only with char
 SELECT my_field FROM my_table WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(my_field, '[0-9]') - only numbers
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).