# SQL: converting a column of numeric and null values to FLOAT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a column of `varchar` type. The column contains 568710 records of numeric (I mean the `ISNUMERIC()` returns 1) and 91 records of null values (i.e., the `ISNUMERIC()` returns 0). Now, I need to convert the column to `FLOAT` without losing the `null` records or replacing them with any other value. Is it possible in SQL?
When I use `CONVERT(FLOAT, [Value])` conversion, I get the following error:

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 48
Error converting data type varchar to float.
```

I read that the `null` can be converted to any type. So it should be possible.

Comment: You can use ISNULL(columnName, '0'). If columnName is NULL then result is 0.

Comment: Note: ISNUMERIC() = 1 doesn't necessarily mean the records contain numbers. If using SQL SERVER 2012+, you might want to use the [`TRY_CONVERT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql) function.

Comment: Isnumeric will also return 1 for values like 45e7.

Comment: @TienNguyen: I want to keep the "null" records as it is in the table after conversion

Comment: You try to use CONVERT(float, ISNULL(columnName,NULL))

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` is not a reliable method to check numeric values. Also when you say `NULL` values make sure it DB `NULL` and not string `null`

Comment: @Prdp: thank you, it was "null" and not "NULL" known to the databases

Comment: @zeropoint - Run a update statement to change all strings `null's` to DB `NULL`. Even after that you may have to check for any non numeric characters present in your data. If you are using `SQL SERVER 2012+` then use `TRY_CONVERT`. For anything less than 2012 check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28370295/sql-server-how-to-test-if-a-string-has-only-digit-characters/28370642#28370642

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can use this**

```
SELECT CONVERT(float, CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(columnName) = 1 THEN columnName ELSE NULL END) FROM TableABC
```

Comment: yes, with this command, I can replaces "(null)" entry with "NULL" accepted for the databases

Answer (score 1):

Try :::

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
ADD NewFloatColumn FLOAT
UPDATE TableName
SET NewFloatColumn = 
CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(VarcharColumn) =1 THEN CAST (VarcharColumn AS float)
WHEN UPPER(VarcharColumn) = 'NULL' THEN null
END
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that the "null" in the database is different from "NULL" known to the databases. I have to modify that.

Comment: @Prdp, sorry for that. now it runs.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select (CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(c) = 1
         THEN (CASE WHEN c LIKE '%.%' THEN c ELSE c + '.00' END)
         ELSE '0.00'
    END)from table_name
```

Comment: thank you. it is not what I want. Actually I wanted to preserve "NULL" entries but converting them to "Float".

Answer (score 0):

I just spent some time scratching my head at the same problem. I was able to resolve this by converting first to int, then to float. Testing shows no data loss as my float column did not contain decimal, it simply had to match the dtype of another column for a later UNION operation.

This was completed on SQL Server 2016.

```
ALTER TABLE table1
ALTER COLUMN column1 int;

ALTER TABLE table1
ALTER COLUMN column1 float;
```